# How do I create an output dataframe that uses user input in the name?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to name a dataframe that includes user input?

For example, I have the following code:

```
start_year = int(input("Enter a start year:"))
end_year = int(input("Enter an end year:"))
selected_jur = input("Enter a jurisdiction number to search for: ")
df_list=[]
df_dict ={}


###this is where I filter my data source to get it ready for the code below

print(f"Combined dataframe of {selected_jur} from {start_year} to {end_year}:")
print(combined_df)
```

I can get everything to work except for naming the dataframe by the 'selected_jur' and time periods. I have to use "combined_df" if I want to conduct further analyses.

Ideally, instead of "combined_df", I'd have the df be something like:

"combined_df_for_{selected_jur}*from*{start_year}*to*{end_year}" instead.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't want to change the name of the variable.  That's for use inside your program, where something like `combined_df` is just fine.  Now, if you want to save it to a FILE, then you might want to generate a file name.  That's quite reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could save that dataframe in a dictionary and use that label as the key, so instead of changing the variable name, you're changing the key name like this:

`df_dict[f"combined_df_for_{selected_jur}from{start_year}to{end_year}"] = combined_df`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a string with the desired DataFrame name using f-strings (formatted string literals) and then use the exec() function to execute a Python statement that assigns the DataFrame to that name.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

start_year = int(input("Enter a start year: "))
end_year = int(input("Enter an end year: "))
selected_jur = input("Enter a jurisdiction number to search for: ")

df_list = []
df_dict = {}

# Assume you have filtered data and combined it into the 'combined_df' DataFrame here

# Create the desired DataFrame name using f-string
df_name = f"combined_df_for_{selected_jur}_from_{start_year}_to_{end_year}"

# Assign the 'combined_df' DataFrame to the dynamically generated name
exec(f"{df_name} = combined_df")

# Now, you can use the dynamically named DataFrame in your further analyses
# For example, you can print its contents like this:
print(f"{df_name}:")
print(eval(df_name))  # Using eval() to access the DataFrame by its name

# You can also access the DataFrame directly without using eval() like this:
print(df_list[0])  # If you added the DataFrame to df_list
print(df_dict[df_name])  # If you added the DataFrame to df_dict
```